# Is this code [theoretically] thread-unsafe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, deadlock, manualresetevent

I'm experiencing a strange deadlock in the code that I've written.

The idea is to implement an asynchronous operation whose **Stop** is synchronous -- the caller has to wait until it completes. I've simplified the part where real work is done to a simple property increment (`++Value`, see below); in reality though, a heavy COM component is invoked which is very sensitive to threads.

The deadlock I'm experiencing is in the `Stop()` method where I explicitly wait for a manual-reset event that identifies a completed operation.

Any ideas what I could have done wrong? The code should be self-contained and compilable on its own.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using ThreadingTimer = System.Threading.Timer;

namespace CS_ManualResetEvent
{
    class AsyncOperation
    {
        ThreadingTimer   myTimer;                 //!< Receives periodic ticks on a ThreadPool thread and dispatches background worker.
        ManualResetEvent myBgWorkerShouldIterate; //!< Fired when background worker must run a subsequent iteration of its processing loop.
        ManualResetEvent myBgWorkerCompleted;     //!< Fired before the background worker routine exits.
        BackgroundWorker myBg;                    //!< Executes a background tasks
        int              myIsRunning;             //!< Nonzero if operation is active; otherwise, zero.

        public AsyncOperation()
        {
            var aTimerCallbac = new TimerCallback(Handler_Timer_Tick);
            myTimer = new ThreadingTimer(aTimerCallbac, null, Timeout.Infinite, 100);

            myBg = new BackgroundWorker();
            myBg.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Handler_BgWorker_DoWork);

            myBgWorkerShouldIterate = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            myBgWorkerCompleted = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        }

        public int Value { get; set; }

        /// <summary>Begins an asynchronous operation.</summary>
        public void Start()
        {
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref myIsRunning, 1);

            myTimer.Change(0, 100);

            myBg.RunWorkerAsync(null);
        }

        /// <summary>Stops the worker thread and waits until it finishes.</summary>
        public void Stop()
        {
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref myIsRunning, 0);

            myTimer.Change(-1, Timeout.Infinite);

            // fire the event once more so that the background worker can finish
            myBgWorkerShouldIterate.Set();

            // Wait until the operation completes; DEADLOCK occurs HERE!!!
            myBgWorkerCompleted.WaitOne();

            // Restore the state of events so that we could possibly re-run an existing component.
            myBgWorkerCompleted.Reset();
            myBgWorkerShouldIterate.Reset();
        }

        void Handler_BgWorker_DoWork(object sender, EventArgs theArgs)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                myBgWorkerShouldIterate.WaitOne();

                if (myIsRunning == 0)
                {
                    //Thread.Sleep(5000);   //What if it takes some noticeable time to finish?

                    myBgWorkerCompleted.Set();

                    break;
                }

                // pretend we're doing some valuable work
                ++Value;

                // The event will be set back in Handler_Timer_Tick or when the background worker should finish
                myBgWorkerShouldIterate.Reset();
            }

            // exit
        }

        /// <summary>Processes tick events from a timer on a dedicated (thread pool) thread.</summary>
        void Handler_Timer_Tick(object state)
        {
            // Let the asynchronous operation run its course.
            myBgWorkerShouldIterate.Set();
        }
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private AsyncOperation myRec;
        private Button btnStart;
        private Button btnStop;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Handler_StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myRec = new AsyncOperation();
            myRec.Start();

            btnStart.Enabled = false;
            btnStop.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void Handler_StopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myRec.Stop();

            // Display the result of the asynchronous operation.
            MessageBox.Show (myRec.Value.ToString() );

            btnStart.Enabled = true;
            btnStop.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            btnStart = new Button();
            btnStop  = new Button();
            SuspendLayout();

            // btnStart
            btnStart.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(35, 16);
            btnStart.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(97, 63);
            btnStart.Text = "Start";
            btnStart.Click += new System.EventHandler(Handler_StartButton_Click);

            // btnStop
            btnStop.Enabled = false;
            btnStop.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(138, 16);
            btnStop.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(103, 63);
            btnStop.Text = "Stop";
            btnStop.Click += new System.EventHandler(Handler_StopButton_Click);

            // Form1
            ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 94);
            Controls.Add(this.btnStop);
            Controls.Add(this.btnStart);
            Text = "Form1";
            ResumeLayout(false);
        }
    }

    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: too much code to read, you need to simplify which code cause problem

Comment: Just for the record, what version of C# are you using?

Comment: The race condition occurs when Stop is called between the myBgWorkerShouldIterate.WaitOne() and myBgWorkerShouldIterate.Reset() in the do work method...

Comment: I have your code running & I can't reproduce the deadlock. Is there any particular scenario it happens under?

Comment: @Chuong Le: I re-organized the code so that the async task is on top. At the bottom there is just accompanying code, necessary to compile and run the program.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like all you're trying to do is have an asynchronous task that starts with the press of a button and stops when another button is pressed.  Given that, you seem to be over-complicating the task.  Consider using something designed for cancelling an asynchronous operation, such as a `CancellationToken`.  The async task simply needs to check the cancellation token's status in the `while` loop (as opposed to `while(true)`) and the `stop` method becomes as simple as calling cancel on the `CancellationTokenSource`.

```
private CancellationTokenSource cancellationSource;
private Task asyncOperationCompleted;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //cancel previously running operation before starting a new one
    if (cancellationSource != null)
    {
        cancellationSource.Cancel();
    }
    else //take out else if you want to restart here when `start` is pressed twice.
    {
        cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        asyncOperationCompleted = tcs.Task;
        BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgw.DoWork += (_, args) => DoWork(bgw, cancellationSource);
        bgw.ProgressChanged += (_, args) => label1.Text = args.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
        bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += (_, args) => tcs.SetResult(true);

        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}

private void DoWork(BackgroundWorker bgw, CancellationTokenSource cancellationSource)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (!cancellationSource.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);//placeholder for real work
        bgw.ReportProgress(i++);
    }
}

private void StopAndWaitOnBackgroundTask()
{
    if (cancellationSource != null)
    {
        cancellationSource.Cancel();
        cancellationSource = null;

        asyncOperationCompleted.Wait();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is different in that the Stop operation is asynchronous. My question was about a **synchronous** Stop. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Kerido If you want some code to execute when the async task finishes could you not just place some code in a handler of the `RunWorkerCompleted` event of the backgroundworker?  Why do you need `Stop` to block?  That said, adding code to make `Stop` block wouldn't be hard, if you're *really* sure you need it.  Keep in mind that you're calling `Stop` from a UI thread.  Blocking the UI thread is generally bad.

Comment: I really do need synchronous Stop. The thread I will be blocking is non-UI in the real-life project. I need Stop to block because the code that calls it is already written. And it cannot be re-written

Comment: @Kerido As I said, converting this to a blocking stop is quite easy; see updated code.  You just need to define a task representing the completion of the task when you start, and mark it as completed when `RunWorkerCompleted` is fired.  Net total of 4 lines of code added.

Answer (score -3):

put this code under ++Value; in Handler_BgWorker_DoWork. Then press the button when you see the output in debug window. Deadlock occurs then.

```
            int i = 0;
            while (i++ < 100) {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Press the button now");

                Thread.Sleep(300);
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
```

Comment: Ok, maybe i should clarify my thoughts. When the user clicks on the stop button while the application is doing its work (here Value++). The timer is already stopping so myBgWorkerShouldIterate.Set(); won't get called again. The bg worker will then wait for myBgWorkerShouldIterate. Then myBgWorkerCompleted will never get set. Correct me if i'm wrong...